# Cannot see uploaded file in sails, and how set up uploaded image location

Tags: javascript, file-upload, sails.js

I have the below file upload script in sails

```
  uploadImage: async function (req, res) {
    req.file("postImage").upload(
      {
        dirname: require("path").resolve(sails.config.appPath, "assets/images"),
      },
      function (err, uploadedFiles) {
        if (err) {
          return res.serverError(err);
        }
        if (uploadedFiles.length === 0) {
          return res.badRequest("No file was uploaded");
        }
        var baseUrl = sails.config.custom.baseUrl;
        var mediaURI = require("util").format(
          "%s/assets/images/%s",
          baseUrl,
          uploadedFiles[0].fd
        );
        return res.json({
          message: uploadedFiles.length + " file(s) uploaded successfully!",
          mediaURI: mediaURI,
        });
      }
    );
  },
```

This successfully upload the image in my `assets/images` folder
but when i tried opening the image in browser at `http://localhost:1337/assets/images/35820a8d-46fa-4a81-bc7b-fc2ca9d07d99.png`

It shows `not found`

I tried `http://localhost:1337/images/35820a8d-46fa-4a81-bc7b-fc2ca9d07d99.png` also still not found

my policy is

```
module.exports.policies = {
  "*": true,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you upload a file in the `${sails.config.appPath}/assets/images` folder that is different from the `${sails.config.appPath}/.tmp/public/images` folder, then you can't get access directly from your URL to the assets folder as `your-domain/images/an-image.png`, to do that you need a controller to download the image where it's stored:

Look at this example how to upload a file using the sails-hook-uploads module:

https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration/blob/master/api/controllers/things/upload-thing.js#L54

And then how to download it:

https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration/blob/master/api/controllers/things/download-photo.js#L50

Comment: I'm using sails --no-frontend, but in full sails app I can view the files in assets folder